# Laravel Blade component method undefined in production but work in local dev

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-forge

I have a component `NoteTag` in *app/View/Components/Notes* and the blade component in *resources/views/components/notes*.

I am using this component in a parent component like this:

```html
<x-notes.note-tag :name="$tag->name"></x-notes.note-tag>
```

`NoteTag` has a method which I want to use in the view:

```php
    public function typeColor()
    {
        return substr(md5($this->name), 0, 6);
    }
```

I reference the method in the view like this:

```html
<span style="border: 2px #{{ $typeColor() }} solid" class="rounded-lg mr-2 px-1 bg-gray-200 text-gray-600 shadow">
    {{ $name }}
</span>
```

This works great in local development, but in production i get this:

```
[previous exception] [object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable $typeColor at /home/forge/loggbok.michaelsimsoe.no/storage/framework/views/e354b32f864ce675974b798281d94fe7f4dd2831.php:1)
[stacktrace]
```

I've also tried to pass it to the view as data:

```php
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.notes.note-tag', ['color' => $this->typeColor()]);
    }
```

Which results in the same error. So I guess there is some mapping issue in production where the component view cant fin the class.

As per [https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31919](http://Blade%20attributes%20not%20being%20passed%20through%20to%20class%20#31919) and [Laravel docs: Manually Registering Components](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#manually-registering-components) I've tried this in the `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
use App\View\Components\Notes\NoteTag;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

...

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    ...

    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::component('note-tag', NoteTag::class);
    }

    ...
```

With no luck.

I've seen multiple mentions of this problem:

- [SO: laravel 7 blade component public methods not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62774513/laravel-7-blade-component-public-methods-not-working)
- [SO: Laravel Components not getting my methods in shared host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62731791/laravel-components-not-getting-my-methods-in-shared-host)
- [Laracasts.com: laravel 7 blade component public methods not working](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-7-blade-component-public-methods-not-working)

Some mention the casing of the class name as an issue. Some mention the manually registering of components. None of them works for me.

I'm using Forge to host the app on DigitalOcean.

I'm using the latest version of Laravel and PHP 8.

[The repo for the application](https://github.com/michaelsimsoe/logbook)

[image: The folder structure in app]
[image: The folder structure of my views]

Any ideas?

Comment: First things first, have you deleted all files in `storage/framework/views`? Then is there a reason that `app/Views/Components/Notes/NoteTag.php` has a class name of `noteTag`? I'd wager that the issue is just a caching one, so `php artisan view:clear` or manually deleting the files in that folder will almost certainly solve this (famous last words ;)).

Comment: @JustCarty I hadn't. Did the view:clear and it did nothing. But! I had changed the `noteTag` filename to `NoteTag` locally. Apparently the change had not been commited to git (how come git doesn't recognize change in capitalization as a change?). I deleted the file, created a new and pushed it and now it works. All this for a missing uppercase N. Thank you! If you reformulate your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer, because who doesn't love reputation?! ;)

---

First things first, have you deleted all files in `storage/framework/views` on the production server?
I'd wager that the issue is just a caching one, so `php artisan view:clear` or manually deleting the files in that folder will almost certainly solve this (famous last words)!

Aside from that, is there a reason that `app/Views/Components/Notes/NoteTag.php` has a class name of `noteTag` (with a lowercase `n`)?
Try changing that to see if that resolves the issue.

Laravel is very particular with it's naming schemes.
All file names must match their namespace and class names perfectly, this includes casing. This is not the case for views, they can be located anywhere, since they are called in render method with the relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

the only solution worked for me was to move my components to App\View\Components folder like

```
php artisan make:component notetag
```