# Laravel app works fine locally but showing "Undefined variable $header" on live server

Tags: php, laravel-8

So I have a Laravel App and on my localhost it works fine, there's no problem.

Then when I deployed my app (I deployed by cloning the GitHub repo straight into Hostinger (shared hosting)), it showed the following error.

[image: Undefined variable $header screenshot]

Here below is the Intro.php file (I have also noticed that when I run dd("random text"); the same error stays visible and with no dd() output)

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\headers\home;

use App\Models\ApiLink;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Intro extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {        
        return view('components.headers.home.intro', [
            'header' => ApiLink::link('translations', 'key=headline'),
            'about' => ApiLink::link('links', 'identifier=about')
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the intro.blade.php is the following code:

```
<div class="h-screen w-full flex justify-center items-center relative overflow-hidden -mt-16" style="background: #f9fdfa;">
    <div class="-mt-80 lg:-mt-36 text-center relative z-10">
        <h1 class="font-light text-4xl sm:text-6xl" id="home-headline">
            {{ $header[0]['value'] }}
        </h1>

        <x-button 
            to="pages.about" 
            :text="$about[0]['page_name']"
            extraStyling="mt-5" />
    </div>

    <video class="z-0 absolute -bottom-32 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 hidden md:block" style="width: 1200px" id="flame-video" muted loop autoplay>
        <source src="{{ asset('videos/flame3.webmhd.webm') }}" type="video/webm">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    {{-- <x-decoration.flame /> --}}

    <x-headers.home.video-container />
    
    <x-headers.home.showreel-bar />
</div>
```

Again, on my localhost everything is working fine. On the server after I deploy the web app, it breaks and shows the error shown on the screenshot.

---

**SOLUTION FOUND**

After doing some more digging, I've stumbled upon this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516457/laravel-blade-component-method-undefined-in-production-but-work-in-local-dev), which solved my problem. The naming convention is PascalCase (for both folders and files within the app/View/Components folder).

Comment: does localhost and the live server has the same PHP version?

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas yes, both PHP version 8

Comment: for test insert your <h1> into a <x-slot> with name `header`, for example : `<x-slot name="header"><h1>...</h1></x-slot>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today , so the takeaway is:

- for component blade side file name should be in sharke_case (exp : alert or alert_message)
- for the component Class side file name should be in CamelCase (exp: Alert or AlertMessage)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).